# Lombok stops working after gradle upgrade

Tags: java, gradle, lombok

My `build.gradle` contains dependency:

```
...
testCompile group: 'org.projectlombok', name: 'lombok', version: '1.18.12'
...
```

When I upgrade my gradle from `4.9` to `6.6.1` I get errors:

```
required: no arguments
found: ...
reason: actual and formal argument list differ in length
```

All my classes that use `@AllArgsConstructor` are failing on `compileTestJava` gradle step. Anyone has a clue why?

Comment: Have you added lombok as `annotationProcessor` like shown in docs ? https://projectlombok.org/setup/gradle

Comment: Just checked and `testAnnotationProcessor` solved it. THX, if you make it to an answer I'll gladly accept.

Comment: I wonder why it worked on old gradle.

Comment: It worked in older versions of Gradle, because Gradle used to scan the other configurations for annotation processors, too. This was changed. Since the processor does not need to be available at runtime, most annotation processors come in two dependencies anyhow (one for the annotations, one for the processor).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also add lombok in `testAnnotationProcessor` :

```
testAnnotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.12'
```

Also adjust the version as you need.

Answer (score 0):

I'll add to the answer.
Here is the link to the documentation: https://projectlombok.org/setup/gradle

Doesn't work for me without **apt**.

It worked for me like this:

```
    compileOnly("org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.28")
    apt annotationProcessor("org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.28")
    testCompileOnly("org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.28")
    apt testAnnotationProcessor("org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.28")
```